# Best way to handle NAs given data type

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I'm trying to reclassify NAs in a dataframe in R.  I want them to be one vlaue if they're character values or factors and another if they're numeric or integers.  I came up with the following if statement but for some reason I'm getting an away.  What's the best way to do this?

```
for(i in ncol(df_eng)) {
  if(class(df_eng[,i]) == "integer") {
    is.na(df_eng[,i]) <- 10219300
  }
  else if(class(df_eng[,i]) == "numeric") {
    is.na(df_eng[,i]) <- 10219300
  }
  else {
    is.na(df_eng[,i]) <- "ABCDEF"
  }
}

 Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = c("2017-05-26 18:20:20",  : 
  replacement has 791 rows, data has 790
```

Comment: I think the assignment with `is.na` is not right.  Check ` v1 <- c(1, 2, NA, 3);
is.na(v1) <- 5`  You may need `df_eng[,i][is.na(df_eng[,i])] <- 10219300`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.  One is the assignment error with `is.na`.  Suppose, we have a vector with some NA values

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, NA, 3)
```

and do the assignment as in the OP's post

```
is.na(v1) <- 5
v1
#[1]  1  2 NA  3 NA
```

This assigns an NA element at position 5 and similarly

```
is.na(v1) <- 10
v1
#[1]  1  2 NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

If the intended behavior is to replace the NA elements with some value say 5

```
v2 <- c(1, 2, NA, 3)
v2[is.na(v2)] <- 5
v2
#[1] 1 2 5 3
```

and second, the loop is only looping at the last column i.e. `ncol(df_eng)`

---

Applying the same logic to OP's example code

```
for(i in seq_len(ncol(df_eng))) {
  if(class(df_eng[,i]) == "integer") {
      df_eng[,i][is.na(df_eng[,i])] <- 10219300
 }  else if(class(df_eng[,i]) == "numeric") {
      df_eng[,i][is.na(df_eng[,i])] <- 10219300
   }  else {
     df_eng[,i][is.na(df_eng[,i])] <- "ABCDEF"
   }
  }
```

Also, note that the loop is stuck at `ncol(df_eng)`.  It should be either `1:ncol(df_eng)` or more correctly `seq_len(ncol(df_eng))` and if it is `data.frame`, then `seq_along(df_eng)`